# Programmatically turn on or off global RestAssured logging to Slf4j

Tags: slf4j, rest-assured, spring-test

I'm trying to configure a RestAssured setup wrapped in Spring test and Junit. Regarding this I'm struggling with making the logging optional based on a config value. I found this link https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#logging which talks about using a logging filter. But I'm not quite sure if this can solve my purpose. I would like to globally turn on or off the RestAssured logging to Slf4j based on a Spring property. Can someone please explain if this is feasible and some hints on how to do this? (At this point I don't intend to bring in Spring AOP for this purpose)

Comment: which actual logging library are you using? Slf4J is _just_ a facade. Logback/Log4j2?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it. I'm using logback.